# Вывод слова по цифре Python

Tags: python, массивы

Напишите программу, которая проходит по всем числам от 1 до 100 и для каждого числа выводит это число, но если оно делится на три — выводит вместо числа «тыры», если на пять — «пыры», а если и на три и на пять — «тыры-пыры».
Я сделал так только с цифрой 3, и не могу понять как делать дальше.

```
array = list(range(1,101))
array2 = []


for i in array:
    if i%3 == 0:
        i = "пыры"
        array2.append(i)
    else:      
        continue

print(array2)
```

Comment: пишите следущий после if блок elif прописываете условие для пяти... и тд

Comment: здесь важен порядок выполнения проверок - сначала проверяйте делится ли число на 15 и после каждой проверки - вызывайте `print(...)` и сразу после этого `continue`

Comment: @MaxU а смысл continue если в if выполнится только 1 верное условие и итерация завершится?

Comment: @Kers, число 30, например, делится и на 15 и на 5 и на 3, а напечатать мы хотим только одну строку при этом. В качестве альтернативы “continue” можно использовать “elif”

Comment: @MaxU что-то не дошло.. а 15 откуда? набросал вариант решения вроде ошибки быть недолжно.. или ее не вижу..

Comment: @Kers, вместо “ if i%3 ==0 and i%5 ==0:” можно написать короче - “if i%15 == 0:”  ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант решения

```
arr = []
for i in range(1,101):
    if i%15 == 0:
        arr.append("тыры-пыры")
    elif i%3 == 0:
        arr.append("тыры")
    elif i%5 == 0:
        arr.append("пыры")
    else:
        arr.append(i)
print(arr)
```

Comment: `i%3 ==0 and i%5 ==0` можно заменить на `i%15==0`

Comment: @n1tr0xs выше в комментах уже обсуждалось

Answer (score 1):

немного изврата:

```
arr = [{0: "тыры-пыры", 3: "тыры", 5: "пары", 6: "тыры", 9: "тыры", 10: "пары", 12: "тыры"}.get(i % 15, i) for i in range(1,101)]
```

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, то их можно задать с помощью кнопки «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Также, чтобы привлечь больше внимания к вопросу, можно [объявить награду](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/571905)

Comment: @VanyambaElectronics это почему же ?

Comment: Подскажите, почему мой вариант медленнее?

Comment: @Vasyl Kolomiets, даже не знаю - у меня не стояла задача сделать максимально быстрый код иначе я бы его сделал через таблицы из 15 элементов - это вообще бы мгновенно работало :)

подозреваю, что чем больше условий, тем медленнее код

Comment: можно так `["-".join(["тыры"]*(i%3==0) + ["пыры"]*(i%5==0)) or i for i in range(1, 101)]`

Answer (score 1):

Да здравствуют однострочники:

```
arr = ['тыры-пыры' if i%15==0 else 'пыры' if i%5==0 else 'тыры' if i%3==0 else i for i in range(1, 101)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение без делений и умножений.
возможно оно быстрее (

```
div3, div5 = 1, 1
for i in range(1,101):

    text3 = "тыры" if div3 == 3 else ""
    text5 = "пыры" if div5 == 5 else ""

    text_answer = "".join([text3,
                           "-" if div3 == 3  and  div5 == 5  else "",
                           text5
                           ])
    print(text_answer if text_answer else i)
    div3 = div3 + 1 if div3 != 3 else 1
    div5 = div5 + 1 if div5 != 5 else 1
```

Вот сравнение и увы мой способ хуже.... Интересно почему.
наверное из за принта в цикле

```
228 µs ± 19.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
13.1 ms ± 1.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Конечно, у меня нет результирующего списка значений, но в задаче о нем ни слова.  Если же список таки нужен, то вот:

rez = [i for i in range(1,101)]
div3, div5 = 1, 1
for i in range(1, 101):

```
text3 = "тыры" if div3 == 3 else ""
text5 = "пыры" if div5 == 5 else ""

text_answer = "".join([text3,
                       "-" if div3 == 3  and  div5 == 5  else "",
                       text5
                       ])
if text_answer:
    rez[i-1] = text_answer

div3 = div3 + 1 if div3 != 3 else 1
div5 = div5 + 1 if div5 != 5 else 1

print(rez)
```

с результатом

```
257 µs ± 10.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Как не странно, мой вариант медленнее, интересно  -  почему.
Вариант от Zhihar  тоже лучше моего:

```
244 µs ± 12.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Это, скорее всего, из-за большого количества операторов `if`